# Jmeter Dashboard Report

Tags: apache, jmeter, report, load-testing, dashboard

Any idea why the request summary pie chart is empty here? I've copied all the things from reportgenerator.properties to user.properties. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please read this documentation:

- jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

And pay particular attention to:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_requirements